# Log In and Web Scrape with Python 3 but action='#' and possibly Java script

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to us Python 3 to scrape my data from Ancestry.com using Beautifulsoup and Mechanicalsoup but I am running into a few issues trying to log in.
Here is the form's HTML on Ancestry:

```
<form action="#" id="signInForm" method="post" class="form formLarge" onsubmit="return false" novalidate="novalidate" data-ui-id="ui1591467547206308">
            <div class="ancGrid">
                <div class="ancCol ancColRow w100">
                    <label id="usernameLabel" for="username" data-error-0="Required" data-error-1="Please enter a minimum of 5 characters for the username/email" data-error-2="Username/email contains invalid characters">
                        Email or Username
                    </label>
                    <input tabindex="1" aria-required="true" class="success required" id="username" maxlength="64" name="username" placeholder="Email Address or Username" type="text" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                </div>
                <div class="ancCol ancColRow w100">
                    <label id="passwordLabel" for="password" data-error-0="Required" data-error-1="Please enter a minimum of 5 characters for the password" data-error-2="Password contains invalid characters">
                        Password
                    </label> [event]
```

1. The HTML form for the site uses action='#', which I've found means that inputs are submitted into the current webpage. Additionally, I see an *[event]*, which states 'event listener', and I think this implies Java Script? If so, do I need a separate import tool to log in?
2. Beautifulsoup cannot find the first form (of two forms). The second form has action="" which does appear.

   ```
   from urllib.request import urlopen
   # specify the url
   quote_page = 'https://www.ancestry.com/account/signin?'
   # query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
   page= urlopen(quote_page)

   # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
   len(soup.find_all('form')) #Out: 1
   ```
3. How can I interact with form 1? When I use `browser.select_form('form[action="#"]')` I get the error LinkNotFoundError. My code:

```
#import urllib.request
#import time
#pip install beautifulsoup4
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#%pip install mechanicalsoup
#import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open('https://www.ancestry.com/account/signin?')
print(browser.get_url())

#browser.select_form('')
###action="#" id="signInForm"
#browser.select_form('form[action="#" id="signInForm"]')
#browser.select_form('form[action="#"]')   #gives LinkNotFound error
browser.select_form('form[action=""]')


browser['username']='USERNAME'
browser['password']='PASSWORD'

browser.submit_selected()
print(browser.get_url())
```

I see a lot of support using mechanize but that does not work for Python 3. I do not know how to check if Ancestry.com is using Java or not, because I can't engage the first form. I am a beginner, so please assume I know nothing, and I won't be offended. (I haven't found a tutorial with action='#' because that query returns few results)

(This person used a different strategy to log into Ancestry, but the site has updated since this code was posted https://github.com/freeseek/getmydnamatches/blob/master/getmyancestrydna.py His code is a little too advanced for me, at my level.)

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider taking a look at this:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

It's very friendly and has javascript support.

Comment: Thanks, I will read though this and learn what I can. Based on what I posted, am I correct in assuming that logging in requires Java and that is why the first form isn't appearing?

Comment: @anansi_mph I think your biggest problem is the captcha. After you go through it, the login fields will appear.

Comment: where or how did you encounter a Captcha? I did not see that or a reference to captcha. I see login fields with the browswer's Inspector, but not with mechanicalsoup. Could you go into detail, please?